# Custom Room-DB Insert statement

Tags: android, android-room

I would like to add a string -- a value entered and changed, occasionally, by the user -- as a tag on all of the records downloaded from a server and inserted into a local, Room managed, db.  I would like my DAO method to take as arguments, the tag and a list of entities.

It looks to me as if there is no straightforward way to do this (insert a constant value for all rows) with a Room-managed db.

Iterating over all the records and setting the constant value seems pretty inefficient.

Is there a good way to:

1. Define a table that contains columns that are never in POJOs (used only as query filters)?
2. Insert a constant value for all rows added in a single insert?

Comment: "Iterating over all the records and setting the constant value seems pretty inefficient" -- calling a setter method on each of your entities isn't the most efficient thing, but the cost of doing that will be swamped by the disk I/O. #1 you could perhaps do via `ALTER TABLE` statements invoked in a `RoomDatabase.Callback`, but you'll be constantly fighting the schema generator. #2 would be cool, but I don't think it is supported.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  I know you don't need it, but if you make that an answer, I'll accept it so everyone can see it.

Comment: I can't rule out some trick that I'm not thinking of. From what I've seen, zero-answer questions get a bit more attention than answered questions. If I think of it, if nobody else chimes in, I'll write up an answer later.

Comment: Seems to me this is just a 1:N relation.  Make a tag table and place a relation in the entitiy table.  Then update the tag table.  A single update to tags will update all linked entities.  I can go into further detail if this is actually what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you but it is not really related to the question at all.